PowerShell Script Failing at insert records
can someone please point me where I made a mistake in below PowerShell script? I'm trying to gather SQL Server related info and load the info into an oracle database which is our repository for keeping the environment related info. The script is spitting error that column Server_Name cannot be null during the update/insert (see log) but when I echo the variable it does contain the Server_Name column value. Perhaps my way of doing the data load is wrong or perhaps there is a syntax error somewhere ? Any help would be appreciated.
#Import necessary modules
Import-Module DBAtools

# Path to the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll file
$oracleDllPath = "D:\oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
# Load the assembly
Add-Type -Path $oracleDllPath

# Initialize logging
$logFile = "D:\PowerShell\log.txt"
Start-Transcript -Path $logFile

WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-1"
try {
    # Step 1: Get all instance names from Central Management Studio and place them in a variable called $Instances
    #$CMSInstance = "CentralManagementServerInstanceName"
    #$Instances = Get-DbaCmsRegServer -SqlInstance $CMSInstance -Group "" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    $Instances = "SQLInst1","SQLInst2"

    # Initialize arrays to hold accessible and inaccessible instances
    $AccessibleInstances = @()
    $InaccessibleInstances = @()

    # Step 2: Ensure each instance is accessible
    foreach ($Instance in $Instances) {
        try {
            # Check if the instance is accessible
            Test-DbaConnection -SqlInstance $Instance -ErrorAction Stop
            # If successful, add to AccessibleInstances
            $AccessibleInstances += $Instance
        } catch {
            # If not accessible, add to InaccessibleInstances
            $InaccessibleInstances += $Instance
        }
    }
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-2"
    # Initialize arrays to hold data
    $serverStageData = @()
    $diskDriveStageData = @()

    # Step 5: Loop through each entry in $AccessibleInstances and gather required information
    foreach ($Instance in $AccessibleInstances) {
        # Example DBAtools commands (replace with actual commands as needed)
        $server = Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance $Instance

        # Gathering Operating System Information
        $os = Get-DbaOperatingSystem -ComputerName $server.ComputerName
        $computerSystem = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $server.ComputerName
        $cpu = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor -ComputerName $server.ComputerName
        $networkConfig = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $server.ComputerName | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } 
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-3"
        # Creating the output object
        $serverInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName               = $server.ComputerName
            OSName                   = $os.OSVersion
            OSVersionCode            = $os.Version
            OSVendorName             = $os.Manufacturer
            OSPatchLevelCode         = $os.Build
            CPUVendorName            = $cpu.Name[0]
            CPUManufacturerName      = $cpu.Manufacturer[0]
            CPUFrequencyMSR          = $cpu.MaxClockSpeed[0]
            PhysicalCoreCount        = ($cpu | Measure-Object -Property NumberOfCores -Sum).Sum
            TotalCoreCount           = ($cpu | Measure-Object -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors -Sum).Sum
            PhysicalRAMGBMSR         = [math]::round($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 2)
            RAMGBMSR                 = [math]::round($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 2)
            DomainName               = $computerSystem.Domain
            OperationalStatusCode    = $computerSystem.Status
            ManagedByServerName      = 'CMS'
            IPAddress                = $networkConfig.IPAddress[0]
            MANAGED_BY_DATABASE_NAME = 'DBAAdmin'
        }
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-4"
        #2.TABLE DISK_DRIVE_STAGE
        $diskDriveInfo = Get-DbaDiskSpace -ComputerName $server.ComputerName | Select-Object @{label='SERVER_NAME';expression={$_.ComputerName}}, @{label='DISK_DRIVE_NAME';expression={$_.Label}}, @{label='CAPACITY_GB_MSR';expression={$_.SizeInGB}}, @{label='USED_GB_MSR';expression={$_.SizeInGB - $_.FreeInGB}}, @{label='FREE_SPACE_GB_MSR';expression={$_.FreeInGB}}, @{label='DISK_DRIVE_LETTER_CODE';expression={$_.Name}}, @{label='LINUX_MOUNT_POINT_PATH';expression={'N/A'}} 

        # Store the gathered information in the respective variables
        $serverStageData += $serverInfo
        #$diskDriveStageData += $diskDriveInfo
        
    }
    

    # Step 6: Connect to the Oracle database
    $oracleConnString = "User Id=myuser;Password=mypwd;Data Source=myoracledb"
    $conn = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($oracleConnString)
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-5"
    try {
        $conn.Open()
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-6"
        Write-Host "Successfully connected to Oracle database."
    } catch {
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-7"
        Write-Host "Failed to connect to Oracle database. Exiting script."
        Stop-Transcript
        Exit 1
    }
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-8"
    # Step 7: Function to update or insert records in Oracle tables.
function Upsert-OracleTable {
    param (
        [string]$tableName,
        [array]$data,
        [array]$columns
    )

        foreach ($record in $data) {
            # Ensure no null values are inserted by checking each value
            foreach ($column in $columns) {
                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($record.$column)) {
                    Write-Host "Column $column cannot be null. Record: $record"
                    throw "Column $column cannot be null"
                }
            }

            # Build the query to check if the record exists by comparing all columns
            $whereClause = @()
            foreach ($column in $columns) {
                $whereClause += "$column = :$column"
            }
            $whereClause = $whereClause -join " AND "

            $checkCmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
            $checkCmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableName WHERE $whereClause"
            $checkCmd.Parameters.Clear()
            foreach ($column in $columns) {
                $checkCmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter($column, $record.$column)))
            }
            $exists = $checkCmd.ExecuteScalar()

            if ($exists -ne 0) {
                # Build the update clause
                $updateClause = ""
                $updateNeeded = $false
                foreach ($column in $columns) {
                    $currentValueCmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
                    $currentValueCmd.CommandText = "SELECT $column FROM $tableName WHERE $whereClause"
                    $currentValueCmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    foreach ($col in $columns) {
                        $currentValueCmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter($col, $record.$col)))
                    }
                    $currentValue = $currentValueCmd.ExecuteScalar()

                    if ($currentValue -ne $record.$column) {
                        $updateClause += "$column = :$column, "
                        $updateNeeded = $true
                    }
                }

                if ($updateNeeded) {
                    # Remove the last comma
                    $updateClause = $updateClause.Substring(0, $updateClause.Length - 2)

                    # Build and execute the update command
                    $updateCmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
                    $updateCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE $tableName SET $updateClause WHERE $whereClause"
                    $updateCmd.Parameters.Clear()
                    foreach ($column in $columns) {
                        $updateCmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter($column, $record.$column)))
                    }
                    $updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                }
            } else {
                # Build and execute the insert command
                $columnsStr = ""
                $valuesStr = ""
                $insertCmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
                foreach ($column in $columns) {
                    $columnsStr += "$column, "
                    $valuesStr += ":$column, "
                    $insertCmd.Parameters.Add((New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter($column, $record.$column)))
                }

                # Remove the last commas
                $columnsStr = $columnsStr.Substring(0, $columnsStr.Length - 2)
                $valuesStr = $valuesStr.Substring(0, $valuesStr.Length - 2)

                $insertCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO $tableName ($columnsStr) VALUES ($valuesStr)"
                Write-Host "Insert Command: $insertCmd.CommandText"
                foreach ($param in $insertCmd.Parameters) {
                    Write-Host "Parameter: $($param.ParameterName) = $($param.Value)"
                }
                $insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            }
        }
    }



WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-14"
    # Update or insert records in Oracle tables with specific columns
    $serverColumns = @("SERVER_NAME", "OPERATING_SYSTEM_NAME", "OPERATING_SYSTEM_VERSION_CODE", "OPERATING_SYSTEM_VENDOR_NAME", "OPERATING_SYSTEM_PTCH_LVL_CODE", "CPU_VENDOR_NAME", "CPU_MANUFACTURER_NAME", "CPU_FREQUENCY_MSR", "PHYSICAL_CORE_CNT", "TOTAL_CORE_CNT", "PHYSICAL_RAM_GB_MSR", "RAM_GB_MSR", "DOMAIN_NAME", "OPERATIONAL_STATUS_CODE", "MANAGED_BY_SERVER_NAME", "IP_ADDRESS", "MANAGED_BY_DATABASE_NAME")
    #$diskDriveColumns = @("SERVER_NAME", "DISK_DRIVE_NAME", "CAPACITY_GB_MSR", "FREE_SPACE_GB_MSR", "DISK_DRIVE_LETTER_CODE", "LINUX_MOUNT_POINT_PATH")
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-15"
    # Specify the schema name for each table
    $serverTable = "MySchema.SERVER_STAGE_T"
   # $diskDriveTable = "MyShema.DISK_DRIVE_STAGE_T"
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-16" 

echo $serverColumns
echo $serverStageData
echo $serverTable
   
    Upsert-OracleTable -tableName $serverTable -data $serverStageData -columns $serverColumns
    #Upsert-OracleTable -tableName $diskDriveTable -data $diskDriveStageData -columns $diskDriveColumns
WRITE-HOST "WE ARE HERE-17"
} catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
    Stop-Transcript
    Exit 1
} finally {
    # Close the Oracle connection
    $conn.Close()
    Stop-Transcript
}

Connection to oracle is working fine
User have enough privileges to insert/update data in the table.
Error:
Column SERVER_NAME cannot be null.
Record: @{ServerName=Server1; OSName=Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard; OSVersionCode=10.0.14393; OSVendorName=Microsoft Corporation; OSPatchLevelCode=14393; CPUVendorName=Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8170 CPU @ 2.10GHz; CPUManufacturerName=GenuineIntel; CPUFrequencyMSR=2095; PhysicalCoreCount=4; TotalCoreCount=4; PhysicalRAMGBMSR=48; RAMGBMSR=48; DomainName=my.domain; OperationalStatusCode=OK; ManagedByServerName=CMSServer; IPAddress=12.11.196.258; MANAGED_BY_DATABASE_NAME=DBAAdmin}
PS>TerminatingError(): "Column SERVER_NAME cannot be null"

An error occurred: Column SERVER_NAME cannot be null

It is unclear when $severStageData and $diskDriveStageData is populated. Is it possible that you could provide a more minimal [mre]?

@lit I can confirm that $serverStageData variable is loaded:
echo $serverStageData
Server1
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
10.0.14393
Microsoft Corporation
14393
Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8170 CPU2.10GHz
GenuineIntel
2095
4
4
48
48
my.domain
OK
CMSServer
10.10.152.125
DBAAdmin
It is this line of code where I am stucked:
Upsert-OracleTable -tableName $serverTable -data $serverStageData -columns $serverColumns

That’s a lot of sample code to pick through. I’d suggest starting at the line that throws the exception and add some logging to validate your assumptions, then work back up the call chain to see where your expectations are failing. For example, start by checking $updateCmd and $insertCmd contain the correct sql command and parameter values - presumably there’s a null value in there you aren’t expecting, which is giving the error, then check the $data and $columns parameters are populated correctly - rinse / repeat until you find something wrong…

The problem is that your $serverStageData object is made up of elements containing these keys:
        $serverInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName               = $server.ComputerName
            OSName                   = $os.OSVersion
            OSVersionCode            = $os.Version
            OSVendorName             = $os.Manufacturer
            OSPatchLevelCode         = $os.Build
            CPUVendorName            = $cpu.Name[0]
            CPUManufacturerName      = $cpu.Manufacturer[0]
            CPUFrequencyMSR          = $cpu.MaxClockSpeed[0]
            PhysicalCoreCount        = ($cpu | Measure-Object -Property NumberOfCores -Sum).Sum
            TotalCoreCount           = ($cpu | Measure-Object -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors -Sum).Sum
            PhysicalRAMGBMSR         = [math]::round($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 2)
            RAMGBMSR                 = [math]::round($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 2)
            DomainName               = $computerSystem.Domain
            OperationalStatusCode    = $computerSystem.Status
            ManagedByServerName      = 'CMS'
            IPAddress                = $networkConfig.IPAddress[0]
            MANAGED_BY_DATABASE_NAME = 'DBAAdmin'
        }

And you are attempting to insert into a table using these column names:
$serverColumns = @("SERVER_NAME",
 "OPERATING_SYSTEM_NAME",
 "OPERATING_SYSTEM_VERSION_CODE",
 "OPERATING_SYSTEM_VENDOR_NAME",
 "OPERATING_SYSTEM_PTCH_LVL_CODE",
 "CPU_VENDOR_NAME",
 "CPU_MANUFACTURER_NAME",
 "CPU_FREQUENCY_MSR",
 "PHYSICAL_CORE_CNT",
 "TOTAL_CORE_CNT",
 "PHYSICAL_RAM_GB_MSR",
 "RAM_GB_MSR",
 "DOMAIN_NAME",
 "OPERATIONAL_STATUS_CODE",
 "MANAGED_BY_SERVER_NAME",
 "IP_ADDRESS",
 "MANAGED_BY_DATABASE_NAME")

The code fails because the names of the properties of the $serverInfo object do not match the $serverColumns that you provide. Update the code so that they match, which may require you to also update the underlying Oracle table which you are inserting data into.
The error you're seeing is due to this part of the function:
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($record.$column)) {
  Write-Host "Column $column cannot be null. Record: $record"
  throw "Column $column cannot be null"
}

Your error message shows:
Record: @{ServerName=Server1;...
Column SERVER_NAME cannot be null

In other words:
"ServerName" <> "SERVER_NAME"

The following short snippet of code reproduces the error:
function Upsert-OracleTable {
    param (
        #[string]$tableName,
        [array]$data,
        [array]$columns
    )

        foreach ($record in $data) {
            # Ensure no null values are inserted by checking each value
            foreach ($column in $columns) {
                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($record.$column)) {
                    Write-Host "Column $column cannot be null. Record: $record"
                    throw "Column $column cannot be null"
                }
            }
            }
}

$serverStageData = @([PSCustomObject]@{"ServerName"="Server1"})

echo $serverStageData

Upsert-OracleTable `
-data $serverStageData `
-columns @("SERVER_NAME")


Good catch! As a solution, I would recommend to get rid of the [array]$columns parameter and use the $data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name array which is directly connected to the actual columns.

@mjsqu Fixing the column name resolved that error but I am now getting another error:
An error occurred: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."

@Ali - Please start a new question, and try to pin down the exact part of the code that is failing. As other commenters have noted, a little investigation on your part will help you get the answers you need yourself, or more quickly from the contributors on this site
